# Build port scanner but i face some issue

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to ask for your advice if you can and guide me on how I will add this 3
in a Python script, I have:

I only have problems with this 2

1. If the Ports is open, it should create a file and add an entry for port number
2. In case of any exception for instance “host is not available”, “host name could not be resolved” or
   due to any other error, you need to write that exception into the same file.

Comment: Your question is unclear and incomplete, please revise and add your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this.

```py
import sys
import socket
from datetime import datetime
  

data = []
  
# Defining a target
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
     
    # translate hostname to IPv4
    target = socket.gethostbyname(sys.argv[1])
else:
    print("Invalid amount of Argument")
 
# Add Banner
print("-" * 50)
print("Scanning Target: " + target)
print("Scanning started at:" + str(datetime.now()))
print("-" * 50)
  
try:
     
    # will scan ports between 1 to 65,535
    for port in range(1,65535):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
         
        # returns an error indicator
        result = s.connect_ex((target,port))
        if result ==0:
            data.append(port)
            print("Port {} is open".format(port))
        s.close()
        with open("data.txt", "w") as e:
            for port in data:
                e.write("Port {} is open".format(port))
                e.write("\n")

         
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\n Exiting Program !!!!")
        sys.exit()
except socket.gaierror:
        print("\n Hostname Could Not Be Resolved !!!!")
        with open("output.txt", 'w') as e:
            e.write("Hostname Could Not Be Resolved")
        sys.exit()
except socket.error:
        print("\ Server not responding !!!!")
        with open("output.txt", 'w') as e:
            e.write("Hostname Could Not Be Resolved")
        sys.exit()
```